# How to read encrypted assertions?

Tags: .net-core, saml, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm writing a SAML2 service provider/relying party. My IdP is returning Assertions in an encrypted form (EncryptedAssertion element). Is this Assertion decryption scenario supported by `ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2`? I'm getting this exception:

```
ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RequestException: There is not exactly one Assertion element.
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.GetAssertionElementReference()
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.GetAssertionElement()
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.Read(String xml, Boolean validateXmlSignature)
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2PostBinding.Read(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, String messageName, Boolean validateXmlSignature)
   at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding`1.ReadSamlResponse(HttpRequest request, Saml2Response saml2Response)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it! I just needed to set `Saml2Configuration.DecryptionCertificate`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are receiving the 'There is not exactly one Assertion element.' error because the Assertion is not successfully decrypted. You are correct to set the DecryptionCertificate setting to decrypt the Assertion.